# Question about finding an UMVUE

Tags: self-study, umvue

[image]

I am trying to find the [UMVUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator) for those two problems. I have found the complete sufficient statistics which are $T=(\sum{x_i}, \sum{y_i},\sum{x_i^2}+1/2\sum{y_i^2})$. which lead to a chi-square...

I am stuck on part two how to find an UMVUE for $(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Note that you can get your $\TeX$ expressions to display correctly by putting dollar signs around them (eg, `$\TeX$`). Can you say more about what you've tried & where you're stuck on the last part?

Comment: I am stuck on how to going on from here or am I on the right track?

Comment: @William Can you find an unbiased estimator for $(\mu_1 - m\mu_2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma^2)$ is

$$T_1=\left(\sum_i X_i,\sum_j Y_j,\sum_i X_i^2+\frac12\sum Y_j^2\right)$$

Equivalently, a complete sufficient statistic is

$$T_2=\left(\overline X,\overline Y,S_X^2+\frac12S_Y^2\right)\,,$$

where $\overline X,\overline Y$ are the sample means, and $S_X^2,S_Y^2$ are the sample variances with divisors $n-1$ and $m-1$ respectively.

As the two samples are independent, so are $\frac{(n-1)S_X^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and $\frac{(m-1)S_Y^2}{2\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{m-1}$.

Therefore, $$\frac1{\sigma^2}\left[(n-1)S_X^2+\frac{(m-1)S_Y^2}2\right]\sim \chi^2_{n+m-2}$$

This yields the following unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ based on $T_2$, which is then UMVUE by Lehmann-Scheffé theorem:

$$\color{blue}{\widehat{\sigma^2}=\frac{2(n-1)S_X^2+(m-1)S_Y^2}{2(n+m-2)}}$$

For the second part, again due to independent samples, one has

$$\overline X-\overline Y \sim N\left(\mu_1-\mu_2,\sigma^2\left(\frac 1n+\frac 2m\right)\right)$$

Then,

\begin{align}
E\left(\overline X-\overline Y\right)^2&=\operatorname{Var}\left(\overline X-\overline Y\right)+\left(E\left(\overline X-\overline Y\right)\right)^2
\\&=\sigma^2\left(\frac 1n+\frac 2m\right)+(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2
\end{align}

So the UMVUE of $g(\mu_1,\mu_2)=(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2$ must be

$$\color{blue}{\widehat{g(\mu_1,\mu_2)}=\left(\overline X-\overline Y\right)^2 - \widehat{\sigma^2}\left(\frac 1n+\frac 2m\right)}$$